# How to customize the search in play CRUD?

Tags: search, playframework, crud, playframework-1.x

I'm using play framework 1.2.7 to create a simple page to search some data on a database.
I already have one of the listing pages with CRUD module. The problem is that the search is a text field that searches in all text columns. I want to customize this.
The default is:

```
#{crud.search /}
```

I imagine I should be able to do something like:

```
#{crud.search }
  ... search fields...
#{/crud.search}
```

But I can't find any documentation about it.
How can I define the fields to search and how to use them?

Answer (score 0):

What it worked for me was to overwrite the list method in the controller that extends from CRUD.

For example:

```
public static void list(int page, String search, String searchFields,
        String orderBy, String order) {
    ObjectType type = ObjectType.get(getControllerClass());
    notFoundIfNull(type);
    if (page < 1) {
        page = 1;
    }
    List<YourObject> yourObjects;
    List<Model> objects;

    yourObjects = YourObject.yourSearch(search); 

            /* I also wanted to keep the standard search
                so from here I also kept the standard code */
            ....
```

}

Comment: I was considering that (actually, I think it's mandatory for what I want).
But that is not exactly what I was asking. I want to change the interface.
ex: have a textbox for name, a dropdownlist for nacionality, etc..